# How i can start with CSLA.net Architecture

Tags: csla

I am new with CSLA.net Architecture .. so any one can guid me how to start with it. i want to create simple insert,update,delete, fetch program using CSLA.net. so that i can better understand architecture.

Answer (score 4):

I'd get the using Csla 4 eBooks which you can buy from store.lhotka.net.  If you want to know why the framework works a certain why, get the expert 2008 business objects in c# book from amazon.  While a bit out of date, it explains the goals of the framework and why things are a certain way.  While how you implement Csla objects has changed a little since then the core ideas are unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

Andy is quite right that the eBooks and Expert Busines Object books are a vital starting point.

Additionally, there is a worked example called ProjectTracker which is discussed in the books which gives examples of the various ways of doing things in CSLA (such as the options for implementing connecting to the data access layer).

The easiest way to install ProjectTracker is to download the full CSLA installer from here: http://www.cslanet.com/Download.html

The last time I installed that file (version 4.5.30) the ProjectTracker project wasn't set up to run with Visual Studio 2013, so if you are new to CSLA and also running VS2013 this post I wrote on the CSLA forum may help you, it describes how to get Project Tracker working in VS2013: http://forums.lhotka.net/forums/t/12200.aspx

The other really helpful resource is the CSLA forum:  http://forums.lhotka.net/forums/.  There are a lot of very experience CSLA users there.